# How to get Glassfish to automatically "find" the index.xhtml and render it through JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am using Glassfish 3.1 and all the reference implementations and I got a question on how I can get Glassfish to see the index.xhtml and render it automatically through JSF, instead of making a index.html and then redirect to index.jsf (which is index.xhtml)? I am just jusing the default mapping in Glassfish (has not added mappings in web.xml) so I can write .jsf in the url field and the xhtml webpages is rendered.

Making a index.html with this: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=index.jsf" />` in every new folder is rather cumbersome and it is probably better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following in the web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

It depends on what `url-pattern` the `Faces Servlet` is mapped to and whether the request-url matches that pattern and if yes then it invokes the `Faces Servlet` and the request will be processed by the `Faces Servlet`.

Comment: It works for all pages apart from index.xhtml in root at the first time; I have a container managed authentication for the whole application (/*) so you need to login. It redirects: http://localhost:8080/myapp/rfRes/skinning.ecss.xhtml?db=eAHL6rC8BQAEkAIG

Comment: @BPDeveloper: How does you web.xml look like?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `<request-mapping>` in web.xml for `index.html` to whatever servlet is responsible for rendering JSF pages.